# How to get response only in english from Google geocode api?

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-geocoding-api

I am using following code , i Have set language to 'en' but i still get result in arcbi.
Is it possible to get only english response ?

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=25.428620,55.465147&sensor=false&language=en

Comment: The set of language is in plist, as I know. 
You need to delete you app and push the new one to override the plist.
Or your could change this value via code.

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10354677/1374307)

Comment: try to add &language=en after key